# How do I set set visibility of items in an expandable list view?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ExpandableListView` and this is my `getGroupView(`) method in my baseExpandableList `Adapter`. When I set `holder2.mPackagenameTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` it works perfectly. All the items in the `ExpandableListView` are invisible. The problem is that i need it to do this when I click a `Button`. So i have an `onClickListener` and when i use the same `holder2.mPackagenameTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` it only makes one of the items invisible instead of hiding the all the items.

I will attach pictures below to give more context.

```
 @Override
                public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    //GroupViewHolder holder;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(JunkCleanActivity.this)
                                .inflate(R.layout.group_list, null);
                        holder2 = new GroupViewHolder();

                        holder2.mPackageNameTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.package_name);

                        //holder2.mPackageNameTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 //this hides all the package names but only here. it only hides single names in other sections of code
                        holder2.mPackageNameTv.setTypeface(shimmer2);
                        holder2.mPackageSizeTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.package_size);

                        holder2.mPackageSizeTv.setTypeface(shimmer2);
                        convertView.setTag(holder2);




                    } else {
                        holder2 = (GroupViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                    }

                    JunkGroup group = mJunkGroups.get(groupPosition);
                    holder2.mPackageNameTv.setText(group.mName);
                    holder2.mPackageSizeTv.setText(CleanUtil.formatShortFileSize(JunkCleanActivity.this, group.mSize));

                    return convertView;
                }
```

[expandable list view normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbT5C.png)

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r6WB.png)

[what actually happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjN4N.png)

Answer (score 0):

It hides only one item may be because you are not targeting the whole item list. My guess is you are only targetting a single item. Please publish the full code where you are using a `onclickListener` so we can go deep in this problem.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: How do I target the whole list? This is basically my button 

`mCleanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
holder2.mPackageNameTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}`

Comment: I need the full code..not only the onclick listener..edit your post by posting the full class

Comment: the rest of it is unrelated to this. It's only a question of how to reference items in an expandable list view.